# mysqldump always back up the same database using different config.cnf file

Tags: php, database, mysql

Take a look to this structure in the server:

```
/home
    /home/user1
        config.cnf
    /home/user2
        config.cnf
    /home/user3
        config.cnf
```

Every user has a associated database to its account in the same server. I have created a php script that back up the database using `mysqldump` command using the credentials for each user in order to backup every database individually. At first place, let me show you the workflow:

1. Declare connection arguments like user, host, data base name

   ```
   $user = env('db_username');
   $password = env('db_password');
   $db = env('db_database');
   $host = env('db_host');
   ```
2. Because using `mysqldump -p{password}` passing the password as argument is to risky, so I proceed to create a temporary config.cnf file having the following content (every config file is ):

   ```
   $config = 'config.cnf';

   // [client]
   // user = the-user
   // password = the-password
   // host = localhost

   $credentials = "[client]\nuser = {$user}\npassword = {$password}\nhost = {$host}";
   \File::put($config, $credentials);
   ```
3. Once the config file is generated, it is time to rum the back up:

   ```
   exec("mysqldump --defaults-extra-file={$config} {$db} | gzip > bk.sql.gz");
   ```

I can confirm that the script run correctly without errors. I have opened the file and the data is there, but every single back up made always returns the data for the first user database, always. I mean:

- Running the script in `/home/user1` backs up user's 1 database;
- Running the script in `/home/user2` backs up user's 1 database;
- Running the script in `/home/user3` backs up user's 1 database;

Also, it is very strange because after running the script I check the config.cnf for each user and the credentials are written correctly. So I am missing something in order to make mysqldump run as expected for every user's database?

Comment: As which user is the script running which is dong the backups?

Comment: the script is running with the respective user. The server is a centos 6 machine. So the script is replicated inside of every user home folder. So, everytime I run the script, I do `su -[the user]` in every case

Comment: Oh, I see! I run the script with the database's user credentials for the user in question.  For example, in order to back up the `database2` I use `user=user2 passowrd=user2`. The host is the same for all: `localhost`

Comment: It is a strange asymmetry that is always `user1` whose data is backed up. Does it help if you use an absolute path to the config file like ` -defaults-extra-file=/home/{$user}/{$config}`? (assuming DB-username = Unix-username, otherwise the script needs one more variable)

Comment: I feel completely stupid. Everything works fine from beginning. After make an exhaustive examination of data in the dumped file I found that the back up is ok for every user/database. Why was I confused? Because for some strange reason the `insert statements`  were put with a huge left-margin, so if you need see the data you need to scroll-right like tomorrow never exists. Very rare. But everythings is ok. Thank you much!